# How to express in an idiomatic and polite way that I'm accepting a suggestion and then adding my own thought?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, politeness

Assuming there is a suggestion to my writing, which mostly makes sense, but would make the most sense after I accepting that suggestion and adding my own interpretation/rephrase there.

I wonder if there is a polite and idiomatic expression to say that I'm accepting that happily but take the liberty to bake my own thought in the updated version?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not-infrequently in that position; when I respond (usually via email) to someone who makes such a suggestion, I usually write "_...that's a good thought; building on that, I think I'll say..._"

Comment: This isn’t a site for seeking advice on polite correspondence. Please read the label.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site, possibly [writing.se] or [interpersonal.se]

Comment: Welcome, minglotus. Please have a read of our [expectations for phrase requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). If you're hoping for a full sentence to be written for you, then I don't think that is in scope here, but if you'd like us to find a more idiomatic way to express a particular part of a sentence, that would be fine, but we'd very much like to know the sentence in question up front so we can tailor our answers accordingly.